# lsblk shows non-existent md partitions after reboot

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm, software-raid

I'm getting weird behaviour while setting up an `mdadm` RAID1 array on debian 8.2.

After I set-up the array, `lsblk` shows:

```
simon@debian-server:~$ lsblk
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
`-sda1                          8:1    0 931.5G  0 part
  `-md0                         9:0    0 931.4G  0 raid1
sdb                             8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
`-sdb1                          8:17   0 931.5G  0 part
  `-md0                         9:0    0 931.4G  0 raid1
sdc                             8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk
|-sdc1                          8:33   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
|-sdc2                          8:34   0   244M  0 part  /boot
`-sdc3                          8:35   0 232.2G  0 part
  |-debian--server--vg-root   254:0    0 228.3G  0 lvm   /
  `-debian--server--vg-swap_1 254:1    0   3.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

After a reboot, `lsblk` shows:

```
simon@debian-server:~$ lsblk
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
`-sda1                          8:1    0 931.5G  0 part
  `-md0                         9:0    0 931.4G  0 raid1
    |-md0p1                   259:0    0 811.6G  0 md
    `-md0p2                   259:1    0 346.1G  0 md
sdb                             8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
`-sdb1                          8:17   0 931.5G  0 part
  `-md0                         9:0    0 931.4G  0 raid1
    |-md0p1                   259:0    0 811.6G  0 md
    `-md0p2                   259:1    0 346.1G  0 md
sdc                             8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk
|-sdc1                          8:33   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
|-sdc2                          8:34   0   244M  0 part  /boot
`-sdc3                          8:35   0 232.2G  0 part
  |-debian--server--vg-root   254:0    0 228.3G  0 lvm   /
  `-debian--server--vg-swap_1 254:1    0   3.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

I don't know where the md0p1 and md0p2 partitions are coming from. My `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` both have nothing about this in them.

`parted` shows one partition on `md0`:

```
simon@debian-server:~$ sudo parted /dev/md0 print
Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md0: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1000GB  1000GB  ntfs
```

Any ideas where the md0p1 and md0p2 partitions are coming from?

I'm setting up the array by doing as follows:

- Delete existing device (I've done this a few times):

  ```
  sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
  sudo mdadm --remove /dev/md0
  ```
- Zero drives:

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=1024
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=1024
  ```
- Create partition tables:

  ```
  sudo parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt
  sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt
  ```
- Create full-disk partitions:

  ```
  sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sda mkpart primary '0%' '100%'
  sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sdb mkpart primary '0%' '100%'
  ```
- Set raid flag on partitions:

  ```
  sudo parted /dev/sda set 1 raid on
  sudo parted /dev/sdb set 1 raid on
  ```
- Create RAID array:

  ```
  sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sd[ab]1
  ```
- Add filesystem (I'm using NTFS, but the problem also happens with ext4)

  ```
  sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/md0
  ```

Comment: did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas where the md0p1 and md0p2 partitions are coming from?

I think they're being interpreted by `kpartx` or equivalent.  (The manpage for `kpartx` says it is "called from hotplug", nowadays this would typically mean `udev`).

I think if you run `kpartx /dev/md0` without any arguments (or with `-v`), it may show the same partitions.

> parted shows one partition on md0

Eh.  parted is likely detecting something else, like the filesystem, or the fact that it's an MD partition, and treating that as more important.  Or parted doesn't support the same set of partition table formats as kpartx.  Or some other differences.  Wouldn't surprise me.

> Zero drives ...

Hmm.  Have you tried `wipefs` instead?  It supports a very large range of partition formats, including filesystems.  Some formats may have magic numbers outside the first megabyte.  For example, GPT partition tables include a "trailer" at the end of the drive, which serves as a backup of the "header" at the start.  `wipefs` specifically handles this case: http://karelzak.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/wipefs8-improvements.html

I think you also need to make sure you wipe `md0` once you've created it.  (I believe `lvcreate` checks for any formats on a new LV and prompts to do this, but the same is not true for `mdadm --create` of a new MD array).

Note `wipefs` is not 100% guaranteed to find the same things `kpartx` looks for.  `kpartx` was created for the lvm/DM projects and uses its own partitioning code.